# Pythonの関数に関する質問

Tags: python, python3

Pythonの関数にかんする質問です。文字列を抽出するプログラムを作成しています。
そのなかでPythonの関数の基本を押さえていなかったため、躓いてしまいました。

環境
Python3.5.2

```
import re

list1 = [
    '5/1:hogehoge町:hogehoge大会',
    '5/2:hogehoge町:hogehoge大会',
    '5/3:hogehoge町:hogehoge大会',
    '5/4:hogehoge町:hogehoge大会',
    '5/5:hogehoge町:hogehoge大会',
    ]

def get_content(self,list1):
    for content in list1:
        pass

def parse_content():
    pass
```

list1に格納されているのは架空のイベントのリストです。
get_content関数でリストから要素を1つずつ取得し、取得した要素はparse_content関数で正規表現などを使って解析したいです。
正規表現は一通りできるのですが、Pythonの関数について基本を抑えていなかったようで、うまくプログラムを製作できません。
理想通りに動かすにはどうすればいいのかご教授おねがいします。

Comment: イベント要素の中身（１つのデータ）は `:` 区切りの様なので、正規表現より `split` で分割してあげる方が良さそうです。

Comment: 「うまくプログラムを製作できません」というのは、コードを書いたけれどエラーが出た（あるいは意図しない結果になった）という事でしょうか？
その場合は書いたコード（とエラーなど）を[「最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)を参考に質問に記載すると、回答が得られやすいです。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/123298

Answer (score 2):

要素を取り出すだけであれば、コメントにあるように組み込み関数のsplitとreplaceでできます。

```
list1 = [
    '5/1:hogehoge町:hogehoge大会',
    '5/2:hogehoge町:hogehoge大会',
    '5/3:hogehoge町:hogehoge大会',
    '5/4:hogehoge町:hogehoge大会',
    '5/5:hogehoge町:hogehoge大会',
    ]



def get_content(l):
    # 出力リストを初期化する
    li = list()

    for contest in l:
        # 「:」で分割
        date, city, name = contest.split(':')

        # 月と日を分割
        month, day = date.split('/')

        # 町名、大会名から「町」「大会」の文字を抜く
        city_sur = city.replace('町', '')
        name_sur = name.replace('大会', '')

        # 出力リストに要素を追加する
        li.append([month, day, city_sur, name_sur])

    return li


get_content(list1)
# =>
# [['5', '1', 'hogehoge', 'hogehoge'],
#  ['5', '2', 'hogehoge', 'hogehoge'],
#  ['5', '3', 'hogehoge', 'hogehoge'],
#  ['5', '4', 'hogehoge', 'hogehoge'],
#  ['5', '5', 'hogehoge', 'hogehoge']]
```

あとはリストの中身を解析すれば良いので、例えば開催町を集計するなどはcollections.Counterを使うと便利です。

```
from collections import Counter

parsed_list = get_content(list1)

# 入れ子のリストからインデックス2個目の要素のみを抽出
cities = [i[2] for i in parsed_list]  
# =>
# ['hogehoge', 'hogehoge', 'hogehoge', 'hogehoge', 'hogehoge']

Counter(cities)
# =>
# Counter({'hogehoge': 5})
```

Answer (score 0):

データの解析をしたい場合は、データサイエンティストが使っているPandas, NumPyを使うと便利です。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

list1 = [
'5/1:hogehoge町:hogehoge大会',
'5/2:hogehoge町:hogehoge大会',
'5/3:hogehoge町:hogehoge大会',
'5/4:hogehoge町:hogehoge大会',
'5/5:hogehoge町:hogehoge大会',
]

# データの読み込み及び「:」で分割
df = pd.Series(list1).str.split(':', expand=True)
# 日付をdatetime型に変換
df['日付'] = pd.to_datetime('2018/' + df[0])
# 正規表現を使って市町を除く
regex_pat = re.compile(r'市|町$')
df['市町村'] = df[1].str.replace(regex_pat, '')
# 普通にreplaceを使えます
df['大会'] = df[2].str.replace('大会', '')
```

これでデータの準備ができました。

```
df   
    0   1           2           日付          市町村     大会
0   5/1 hogehoge町   hogehoge大会  2018-05-01  hogehoge    hogehoge
1   5/2 hogehoge町   hogehoge大会  2018-05-02  hogehoge    hogehoge
2   5/3 hogehoge町   hogehoge大会  2018-05-03  hogehoge    hogehoge
3   5/4 hogehoge町   hogehoge大会  2018-05-04  hogehoge    hogehoge
4   5/5 hogehoge町   hogehoge大会  2018-05-05  hogehoge    hogehoge
```

Pandas, NumPyには、データ解析のための便利な機能を持っています。
日付、市町村、大会のカラムを取り出したい場合は、

```
df[['日付', '市町村', '大会']]
```

市町村別の件数を知りたい場合は

```
df['市町村'].value_counts()
```

データをExcelファイルに書き出したいときは

```
df.to_excel('data.xlsx')
```

Pandasはベクトル演算ができるのでループがなくなってストレートにプログラムが書けます。

また、Jupyter Notebookを使うと実行結果を記録しながら解析作業を進められます。
Google Colaboratoryの方にも同じものアップしておきます。Google Colaboratoryは、無料でGoogle IDがあればJupyter Notebookを使えます。

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16yKmNo3Z13rbkH_w2f6Gcd0TvME3ykpg